# Configuring Jenkins To Deploy on AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-eks

I am trying to connect jenkins with the AWS EKS to create deployment pipelines. AWS using aws-iam-authenticator and jenkins-kubernetes plugin requires certificate and credentials to connect to the EKS Kubernetes cluster.

So far i haven't been able to figure out what to configure in credentials, i have tried service account but that didn't help.

Any help in the pointing to the documentation to achieve that would be highly helpful

Comment: did you run [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) and [that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below URL for setting up your CI/CD for kubernetes just replace codebuild and codepipeline with jenkins and trigger the Lambda function from Jenkins itself.

> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/continuous-deployment-to-kubernetes-using-aws-codepipeline-aws-codecommit-aws-codebuild-amazon-ecr-and-aws-lambda/